How To Get Morningstar Unique Stock IDs
I have been trying to extract every piece of information I can from Morningstar's Investor platform and save it offline for free to integrate for a different use case;
I have figured out how to unofficially leverage the API to get outputs as I desire but the bottleneck is that they use a unique identifier system- called Morningstar Tickers.
Each stock has it's own ticker like- 0P000003GU
Does anyone have any idea how I can get these tickers for at least all S&P stocks; has anyone tried this before?
Any suggestions welcome.
